# PHP Multi-tag search

Tags: php, search, tags

Got this script partially working, but if there are 3 tags on 1 video, and I type all 3 tags, the video comes back 3 times, not sure how to rectify this.

```
$search = sanitize($_GET['search']);
$array = explode(" ", $search);
foreach($array as $mySearch)
{
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos`");
  while($mad = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
    if(strpos($mad['tags'], $mySearch))
    {
      // show results
      echo "<div class='comment_1'>$mad[title]</div>";
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a query `SELECT *` inside a foreach loop? You're just selecting everything for every instance of `$array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Got this script partially working

Well that's fine, however, scripts are like being pregnant: There is no partially. A system either works or not, not much between the lines.

You have a logical problem here, resulting from a wrong order of processing with your control structures.

The normal procedure is:

1. Validate and process the input data.
2. Work with the data, transform it. In your case, use it to fetch data from the database.
3. Output the data fetched from the store.

In your script you mix all these three things into each other instead of doing one part after the other:

```
$tags_array = get_tags_array_from_input();

$result = mysql_query_result_based_on_tags_array($tags_array);

display_results($result);

/**
 * exemplary only
 */
function mysql_query_result_based_on_tags_array(array $tags)
{
    $mask = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE tags REGEXP '%s'";
    $sql  = sprintf($mask, implode('|', $tags));

    return mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: When I read the question I have to assume that the database column `tags` is a VARCHAR column. The tags might be saved in a -whatever- separated list. The IN() statement wont work

Comment: @hek2mgl: In that case, right, makes sense what you say. IN is not the tool of choice then, using REGEXP for the (trivial) example.

Answer (score 1):

You could change it up a little and do:

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
$search = preg_replace('/\s+/m', '|', $search);
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` where tags regexp '{$search}'");
while($mad = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
   // show results
   echo "<div class='comment_1'>{$mad['title']}</div>";
   break;
}
```

Note that I changed your `mysql_*` functions to their `mysqli_*` equivalents since they are deprecated. I also reduced your code to just one loop and added the search terms to your query

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$search = sanitize($_GET['search']);
$array = explode(" ", $search);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos`");
while($mad = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    foreach($array as $mySearch) {
        if(strpos($mad['tags'], $mySearch)) {
            // show results
            echo "<div class='comment_1'>$mad[title]</div>";
            continue 2;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably taking a little bit of a backwards approach here.  You should utilize your search tags in the query, so you don't need to return the entire table.  You should probably also normalize your tags into a tags table and a videos_tags table which expresses a many to many relation between them.  You would then do you search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
videos
INNER JOIN videos_tags ON videos.video_id = videos_tags.video_id
INNER JOIN tags ON videos_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE tags.tag_text IN ('tag 1', 'tag 2', etc.)
```

This would make your model much more sustainable as your application grows.